# Uploading image using Canvas HTML5, how to send file name and file size with the same post action?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, asp.net-mvc-4, canvas

i have a problem to solve with my custom image uploader (HTML5 Canvas based).

I'm using **ASP.NET MVC 4** in the server side and trying to send a image using a post ajax (because i'm doing a post ajax of a FormData + images in base64 string)

I'm getting the base64 string from the canvas using **toDataURL()**

```
canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.7)
```

To save this image, i send the base64 string to the server, but i can't get the **file name** and **file size** like a normal form post, ( in a normal post i receive a **HttpPostedFileBase** )

So, someone know how can i send extra data with the image (base64 string)?

Comment: Check out this thread: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2665/saving-html-5-canvas-as-image-in-aspnet-mvc

Comment: thanks for answer, but my upload is working (very similar with the content in the link), i don't explain before but, in my canvas, i receive a image to upload, then i perform some modifications, like resize and set background colors and apply borders on the image, when i upload, i need send some custom data, its my problem